# How do I reduce the latency to AWS RDS database?

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services

I have a Laravel application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and a MYSQL RDS Database. In localhost a query that might take .002 seconds will take .2 seconds in the live server, thats a 100x hit on performance, this becomes incredibly problematic when I have to load several datapoints, a simple table that will take half a second to load on Localhost now takes 13 seconds to load live.

I figured out the problem is the latency between the instances, so I created an RDS database connected directly to the Elastic Beanstalk application, and viola! Even faster than localhost...However having your database tied to your EC2 instance is awful and non scalable.

I have tried everything, from reducing the queries, trying different queries, I tested without eloquent and used raw MYSQL, and that does not solve the problem, the queries are not the problem, the latency is!

I am sure I am doing something wrong. The two instances are in the same timezone, I tried with higher tier databases and the latency does get reduced, but not significantly, amazon aurora reduced it from 13 seconds to 3 seconds which is still unacceptable. So the question is, how do I configure my elastic beanstalk + RDS so that it performs well...at least as good as in localhost? How do I reduce that latency?

Thanks!

Comment: if it works well when you " created an RDS database connected directly to the Elastic Beanstalk application" it should work same when RDS is created separately. What are the differences in settings used in the first and second case?

Comment: None, the ONLY change was removing the .env database credentials and adding the environmental variables: RDS_HOSTNAME,RDS_DB_NAME, etc. in database.php

Comment: when you ssh into the instance, and try accessing the db using `mysql` it is also slow, or only when using your larver application?

Comment: Create RDS in the same region as your EC2 instance is in. Also create assign a same VPC to RDS instance.

Comment: Ah thats a good point! Its way faster in mysql-workbench, just ran a query, it executed in 0.016sec in workbench, 0.26 in the Laravel APP, any idea why this is happening? Where could I start the debugging process? I am using plain eloquent nothing else.

Comment: @mariolanda that's the case I think you should check your SSL settings, and try to run the same query which is generated by the Eloquent and see the results.

Comment: the workbech was on the EB instance or your local workstation? I'm trying to establish if this is EB instance issue, larver specific only or just RDS in general (which seems now to be not the case).

Comment: I am connecting from my local machine using workbench. And I got the above results, and running the same query generated by eloquent is how i got those results (->toSql()) : 0.016sec in workbench, 0.26 in the Laravel APP

Comment: Have you found the workaround for this yet? @mariolanda

Comment: Hello Dejan, it seems like even this load which is nothing for a local server exhausts the CPU cores in AWS, you need to pay for a higher tier DB and make sure that the DBS are in the same server zone.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing database latency is a general problem for all distributed databases. Amazon AWS is designed for distributed queries, but such distributed nodes need to check synchronicity with respect to the requested data (metadata) and data needs to be collected.

Unless one node cannot hold the dataset in memory, the whole system will react significantly slower than having a single node database within the system, that queries the data. Even such latency gaps of 10x or even 100x are possible. To overcome this latency by distribution, you will need approx 20x-500x nodes, depending on the latency of the network, compared to the latency of the local disk or local memory.

So you will need a real big rds setup to gain from distribution in general.